# Running script when a specific cell in another workbook changes

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to create a script which detects when cell B2" in another workbook changes.

Once the change is detected run the macro RUNALL which has already been created and is working. RUNALL will run a number of macros, which saves as a pdf and sends an email to the customer.

```vb
Sub Worksheet_Changes(ByVal Target As Range)
' Run the code when cell B2 is changed
If Target.Address = Workbook("M:\Wholesale\Test.xlsx").Sheet("Sheet1").Range("B2").Address Then
    Call RUNALL
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Open first workbook from second then do `application.run RUNALL`?

Answer (score 2):

Read up on Application events: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/create-application-level-event-handler

In a class module  `clsAppEvents`:

```vb
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents app As Excel.Application
Private cellToMonitor As Range

Private Sub app_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If Sh.Parent.Name = cellToMonitor.Worksheet.Parent.Name Then
        If Sh.Name = cellToMonitor.Worksheet.Name Then
            If Not Application.Intersect(Target, cellToMonitor) Is Nothing Then
                Debug.Print "Changed " & cellToMonitor.Address & " on " & _
                             Sh.Name & " in " & Sh.Parent.Name
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set app = Application
End Sub

Property Set TheCell(c As Range)
    Set cellToMonitor = c
End Property
```

In a regular module:

```vb
Option Explicit

Private obj

Sub Tester()
    Set obj = New clsAppEvts
    Set obj.TheCell = Workbooks("Book2").Sheets(1).Range("A3") 'for example
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

As BigBen has pointed out, the **Worksheet_Changes** is triggered only when there is a change in the sheet where your script is specifically located, therefore you should move the macro to the sheet's code located on the other workbook (the one that suffers the change).

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$B$2" Then
        Application.Run ("'M:\Wholesale\My_Book.xlsm'!RUNALL")
    End If
End Sub
```

Since the RUNALL macro will be located in a different workbook, you should use the `Application.Run()` method as findwindow also pointed out to make the reference to a different workbook. In this case "My_book.xlsm" is the one containing the RUNALL macro.

Moreover, note that `Workbook("M:\Wholesale\Test.xlsx").Sheet("Sheet1").Range("B2").Address` will only return `$B$2` making no difference between the two workbooks.